# www and non-www redirection showing different pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I have a domain "example.com".

Where I had hosted a static html site then recently I switched to wordpress.

Now "www.example.com" is showing my current wordpress theme site whiel non-www "example.com" is showing the homepage of previous html page.

In webmaster I have set my preferred domain as "www.example.com" in my godaddy account I had not set any domain redirection.

And I am confused also as i remember it was showing new site even after installing WordPress but after installing Yoast SEO it happened. (I am not sure about this just a feeling).

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried with another computer that had never accessed the old website?

Comment: Are the old website files still on the server?

Comment: show your .htaccess file code there.

Answer (score 0):

I redirect the link from my domain central from non-www to www and its fixed now.